# Discord.js Ban Error when trying to use a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a bot and have it have a ban command. without a reason, the ban command works great. But once I give it a reason, it just stops working and gives me this error: 
`{"title":"Go Vote for the Server!","description":"I've just finished posting the server to top.gg, one of the largest server listing sites. Please go vote for the server [here](https://top.gg/servers/754062115123232938/vote) so that more people can learn about it. It would really help the server grow. ","color":10426392,"footer":{"text":"© The Red Door, 2020"}}`

If you have any idea how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated. Here is my current code for banning users:

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === config.modRole)) {
            // Looks for the mentioned user
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if(user){
                // Checks if the user mentioned is in the server
                const member = message.guild.member(user);
                if(member){
                    // Bans the user
                    member.ban(config.banMessage).then(() =>{
                        message.reply(`sucessfuly banned ${user.tag}.`);
                        console.log(`Sucsessfuly banned ${user.tag} in ${message.guild}`)
                    }).catch(error =>{
                        // Catches any errors
                        message.reply(`I encountered an error when trying to ban ${user.tag}`);
                        console.log(`Error banning ${user.tag} in ${message.guild}`);
                        console.error(error);
                    })
                } else {
                    message.reply(`That user isn\'t in the server.`)

                }
            } else {
                message.reply(`you need to specify a valid user to ban!`)
            }
        } else {
            message.reply('you do not have permission to use this command!')
            console.log(`${message.author} tried to use the ban command in ${message.guild} but did not have sufficient permissions`)
        }
    },
```

Comment: That's not an error, and there's also no usage of a "reason" in the code you provided.

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong thing. Ill copy the right error once I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. The ban command has a different method of using a reason compared to the kick command. For the kick command, you can simply use message.author.kick("reason") as said [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick). But for the ban command you use message.author.ban({reason: "reason"}) as said [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban).